# How to get Co-Author-Plus data via shortcode

Tags: wordpress

with the following code I want to show the authors via the Co-Author-Plus plugin via shortcode using a php file. But this doesnt work. It just returns nothing. You know why?

Update code:

```
<?php function coauthorplus_function() {
    ob_start();
                            $coauthors = get_coauthors();
                            $len = count( $coauthors );
                            if ( (function_exists( 'coauthors_posts_links' )) && ($len > 1) ) { ?>
                                <div class="authors-container">
                                    <div class="author-image">
                                        <?php echo get_avatar( $coauthor->user_email, '80'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="author-data-details">
                                        <div class="fdescription fdescriptions">Dieser Artikel wurde in Ko-Produktion durch folgende Autoren erstellt:</div>
                                        <div class="authors-name">Von <?php coauthors_posts_links(); ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            <?php 
                            } else {
                                global $post;
                                $author_id=$post->post_author;
                                foreach( get_coauthors() as $coauthor ):
                                    ?>
                                <div class="author-container">
                                    <div class="author-image">
                                        <?php echo get_avatar( $coauthor->user_email, '80'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="author-data-details">
                                        <div class="author-name">Von <?php coauthors_posts_links(); ?></div>
                                        <div class="fdescription"> <?php echo $coauthor->description; ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                                <?php endforeach;
                                 }
                                 return ob_get_clean(); } add_shortcode('coauthorplus', 'coauthorplus_function'); ?>
```

In my function.php which is on the same place in the webspace I included the following:

```
include('coauthorplus.php');
```

Comment: You can't echo shortcode output. You need to use output buffering to return the content.

Comment: Ok, and how I should do that?

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588554/wordpress-shortcode-is-always-at-the-top-of-the-content/60588756#60588756

Comment: Super nice – it works!

Comment: But when I edit some posts I get always a blank page after saving my update. When I delete the following in the functions again:

`include('coauthorplus.php');`

This problem is away. Whats wrong with this code?

Comment: I get this errors – can you help me with that? @HowardE

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/htdocs/XXX/wp-content/themes/XXX/coauthorplus.php:39) in /www/htdocs/XXX/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6712


Warning: ... (output started at /www/htdocs/XXX/wp-content/themes/XXX/coauthorplus.php:39) in /www/htdocs/XXX/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 1310

Warning: ... (output started at /www/htdocs/XXX/wp-content/themes/XXX/coauthorplus.php:39) in /www/htdocs/XXX/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 9`

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest code?

Comment: What's on line 39? If I copy your code, it's only 34 lines.  Also - how does get_coauthors work, if postid isn't set?  This isn't inside a loop, so looking at this https://github.com/Automattic/Co-Authors-Plus/blob/ad8bbccc2498756267465a1dbd64ab9ce9bf4222/template-tags.php#L3 it appears you will need to pass the postid to your shortcode... right?

Comment: Hey @HowardE, I have no line 39. I cant said it to you why it shows the authors. I am not so good in understanding the code. I just copy it from previous solutions.

Maybe you can help me to just get the coauthors in the right way?

Comment: Delete the closing ?>

Comment: Nice, that was it. THank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238465/discussion-between-howard-e-and-johny).