# When I add this code in functions.php, its breaks the site, What is Wong in my short code ? Chart.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, chart.js

```
function chartJS_shortcode(){
?><canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas><?php

<script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
    </script>

}

add_shortcode("chartJS", "chartJS_shortcode");
```

I want to create a chart shortcode through chart.js and when I add this code in functions.php, its breaks the site. Please tell me what is wrong with this code? however, its code works fine when I paste into the page.

Comment: Your code is JavaScript and you're placing into a PHP file, that won't fly. At least, not without putting it into a string. Please show how you're implementing this script in your shortcode.

Comment: Please check again, I have updated the code.

Comment: You are opening `<?php` after the closing `</canvas>` tag, making everything after the opening `<?php` read as PHP again.

Comment: You can't echo or print to screen any shortcode output. You must return it. Use output buffering.

Comment: Does this answer help? [Wordpress shortcode is always at the top of the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588554/wordpress-shortcode-is-always-at-the-top-of-the-content)

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier What is wrong with PHP ??

Answer (score 0):

Place the JavaScript in it's own file. Reasons for doing this is that you only want to load the script once and it keeps your shortcode a bit cleaner. Let's call that file `chart.js`

Let's register that script for enqueueing with [`wp_register_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/), meaning that it will be added to the page whenever we give the signal.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
  wp_register_script('chartJS', 'your-assets-folder/chart.js', [], false, true);
});
```

Then for the shortcode. Because the script is now in a separate file, the code is much cleaner. Here we call `wp_enqueue_script` to add your JS to the bottom of the page.

The most important part here is returning the HTML as a string. This will be the output of the shortcode.

```
add_shortcode('chartJS', function($atts, $content = null) {
  wp_enqueue_script('chartJS');
  return '<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>';
});
```